# EWS EmailMessage Move acts as Copy

Tags: email, office365, exchangewebservices

Last day we have a problem with the EWS EmailMessage Move()
The Email message must be moved from one of Public Exchange Folder to another Public Exchange Folder.
All works perfect untill last day. Now instead .Move() - application made a Copy of message and leave original message in the incoming folder.

Here a simple code

```
Dim loFolderId As New FolderId(lc_EWSFailFolderID)
Dim loNewItem = loItem.Move(lc_EWSFailFolderID)
```

The code produce no exception, but instead Move() doing copy.
Does someone has similar problem?

I have try to debug. No exception happens on Item.Move()

Answer (score 0):

we have same problem since last night. If you modify the code by turning the "Move" into EmailMessage.Copy and then EmailMessage.Delete everything works. Apparently something has changed in the behavior of Move in ExchangeWebService.