# EWS EmailMessage Move failed

Tags: office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, move

Two monthes ago i wrote a topic where I reported about the EWS email message.Move() has been copied the message to destination exchange public folder, but not remove message from source public exchange folder.
[EWS EmailMessage Move acts as Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77652962/ews-emailmessage-move-acts-as-copy). We made an owerwork and if the message still located in source folder, delete it.

Now our customers reports us about another problem (not all, but some of them, but quantity of support messages growing)

The **MailItem.Move()** itself produce an error **"The move or copy operation failed"**.
The same code works long time since last friday (23.02.2024)
It seems MS making some ExchangeServe cloud update and move function stop to work.
Is someone has similar problem with  MailItem.Move()? and how it possible to solve it now?

Comment: It is not clear what code/payload exactly is used in your scenario.